# In T-SQL, how can I guarantee that a column value is updated only after all other column values in the same UPDATE statement have been updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'd like to do a sort of "bulk update" of a table using an inner join.  Here's how it works.

There are two tables in question, one of which is being updated.  I'll call the one being updated `OriginalTable` and the other one `UpdateData`.

Both `OriginalTable` and `UpdateData` contain a PK column called `Id`, which we join on later.  `OriginalTable` contains a number of other columns, all of which are nvarchars, I'll call these the data columns.  Finally, `OriginalTable` also contains a *Checksum* column, which I'd like to have contain a SHA1 hash of the string concatenated data in a given row's data columns.  `UpdateData` contains a subset of the data columns in the `OriginalTable`, and that's what's used to specify what to update the data in `OriginalTable` to.

If a value in `UpdateData` is a non-empty string or NULL, then I'd like to update the corresponding row in `OriginalTable` with that value.  If the value is an empty string, then I don't want to modify the value of `OriginalTable` row.

Let's say that the data columns in `OriginalTable` are: `FirstName`, `LastName`, `MI`, `Age`.  Let's say the data columns in `UpdateData` are: `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`.  This basically means we're updating information for everything but `MI`.

I can accomplish this update with this SQL:

```
UPDATE T
SET FirstName = CASE UD.FirstName WHEN '' THEN T.FirstName ELSE UD.FirstName END,
    LastName = CASE UD.LastName WHEN '' THEN T.LastName ELSE UD.LastName END,
    Age = CASE UD.Age WHEN '' THEN T.Age ELSE UD.Age END
FROM #OriginalTable T 
INNER JOIN #UpdateData UD 
  ON T.Id = UD.Id;
```

This is well and good.  Now, the challenge I'm facing is that when it comes to updating the Checksum value for a row, I don't know how to guarantee that the hash calculation will occur only after the other rows have been updated first.  I should mention that it's essential that the checksum calculation occurs in the same statement.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE T
SET FirstName = CASE UD.FirstName WHEN '' THEN T.FirstName ELSE UD.FirstName END,
    LastName = CASE UD.LastName WHEN '' THEN T.LastName ELSE UD.LastName END,
    Age = CASE UD.Age WHEN '' THEN T.Age ELSE UD.Age END,
    Checksum = CONVERT(varchar(40), HASHBYTES('SHA1', T.FirstName + T.LastName + T.MI + T.Age), 2)
FROM #OriginalTable T 
INNER JOIN #UpdateData UD 
  ON T.Id = UD.Id;
```

I need to calculate the value of the Checksum column with the values in `OriginalTable` after the update.  How can I accomplish this hash calculation in the same UPDATE statement, guaranteeing it's calculated for data after the other columns have been updated?

Comment: Can't you just make it two statements but wrap them in a transaction? Is there a reason you need it done in a single statement? Is it just for atomicity?

Comment: An update is not a whole series of events. It happens all at once. If you want to do this you will need add all the case expressions inside your HASHBYTES function or do a second update. The way you have it coded your HASHBYTES will use the current value, not what the new value is going to be.

Comment: Honestly I would consider making your Checksum a computed column. That would avoid you having to wrestle with it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (untested):

```
UPDATE T
SET FirstName = UD.FirstName,
    LastName = UD.LastName,
    Age = UD.Age,
    Checksum = CONVERT(varchar(40), HASHBYTES('SHA1', UD.FirstName + UD.LastName + T.MI + UD.Age), 2)
FROM #OriginalTable T 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT T1.Id,
          CASE UD1.FirstName WHEN '' THEN T1.FirstName ELSE UD1.FirstName END AS FirstName,
          CASE UD1.LastName WHEN '' THEN T1.LastName ELSE UD1.LastName END AS LastName,
          CASE UD1.Age WHEN '' THEN T1.Age ELSE UD1.Age END AS Age
      FROM #OriginalTable T1
         INNER JOIN #UpdateData UD1 ON T1.Id = UD1.Id) AS UD
  ON T.Id = UD.Id;
```